# reload global variables in ipython notebook

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a module that helps me with code and global variables, and a run file on a notebook.
I use `from my_module import *` to import it and it works. When I change function definitions on the module, they `autoreload` on the notebook just fine, but the global variables I defined **do not** when I change them in the module - I have to restart the kernel.

Is there a way to achieve autoreload for them without putting them inside a function or class?

Answer (score 1):

Module named [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) allow to access to import internals. Especially, it provide function [`importlib.reload()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_module)
```

`importlib.reload()` correctly re-read module and reset global variables.

`importlib` is only available since Python 3.1. For older version, you have to use module [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html).